# How to concat two video webm files over nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, server-side, fluent-ffmpeg

I am creating a web video conferencing app where there are many people comunicating each other, and every 60 seconds I want to upload webm files (one video webm file for one person) to the server and add to the previous file.

Is it possible to append video file?.

I use this code:

```
ffmpeg()
    .input(filePathTMP)
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
    })
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log('Merging finished !');
    })
    .mergeToFile(filePath, filePathBase + 'temp');
```

This code combines two files (filePathTMP and filePath) and and convert them before you join them, wasting time. Is there a similar command that combines the files without decoding?

Comment: I use this call "fileBuffer = new Buffer(file.contents, "base64");" My files are base64 format, I try to append but it doesn't work.

Comment: I simply write the buffer using this "var logStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePathTMP, {
        'flags': 'w',
    });
    logStream.write(fileBuffer);"

Comment: is non streaming format because its base64 file audio/video. 
If useful to know, I use mediastreamrecorder api to record videos.

Comment: I've tried to concatenate the buffer using createWriteStream using flags 'a', you know a better way to concatenate all, a little better mode.

Comment: You can use `HTMLMediaElement.captureStream()`, `MediaRecorder` to concatenate one or more videos at an `.html` `<video>` element to a  `Blob` then save file.

Comment: Ok, and What can I use on the server side? Client-side I have blob file, can I send this to server and concatenate server side?

Comment: https://transloadit.com/demos/video-encoding/concatenate-two-videos/

Comment: check this link

Comment: I saw and thank @Adil but I do not care, I wanted to know how to concatenate two blob server side.

Comment: https://github.com/muaz-khan/ConcatenateBlobs

Comment: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/ConcatenateBlobs/

Comment: same thing u can do on server side

Comment: get two blob concatenate and save them

Comment: @Adiii I don't found a solution. can you help me?